# Perl dynamic / symbolic function reference

Tags: perl, reference

Given a package name `$package` and a function name from within that package `$function`, I can create a reference to that function:

```
my $ref = eval( "\\&${package}::${function}" );
```

As a complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

package foo;

sub func()
{
    print "foo::func\n";
}

package main;

my $package = "foo";
my $function = "func";

my $ref = eval( "\\&${package}::$function" );
$ref->();
```

I do not particularly like that `eval()` in there and wonder **if the same result could be achieved without `eval()`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is this:

```perl
my $ref = \&{ "${package}::$name" };
```

or

```perl
my $ref = \&{ $package . "::" . $name };
```

Using an expression producing the name of a variable where a variable name is expected is called a [symbolic reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Symbolic-references). These are usually forbidden by `use strict;` (specifically `use strict qw( refs );`), but `\&` is exempt.

Answer (score 1):

Using strings to refer to subroutines is seldom the right way. If you are doing it this way, you are most likely doing something wrong. You can use a code reference to store a reference to a function, in a scalar or hash. The hash allows you to correctly look up code references via string inputs.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package foo;
sub func() {
    print "inside foo::func (@_)\n";
}

package main;

# use a direct reference, in a scalar variable
my $ref = \&foo::func;
$ref->(1,2,3);

# ...or in a hash
my $pack = "foo";
my $func = "func";
my %table = ( foo => { func => \&foo::func } );
$table{$pack}{$func}->(qw(a b c));
```

Output:

```
inside foo::func (1 2 3)
inside foo::func (a b c)
```